# ctypes: Correctly subclass c_void_p for passing and returning custom data types, by example

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working with `ctypes` and cannot seem to figure out how to work with custom data types.  The hope is to have a Python interface to the public methods of a C++ `cell` class and a C++ `cellComplex` class.

My current problem is working with the C function called `get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim()`, defined below under `extern "C" {...`.  This function has been written to return a `void *` which is *really* a `std:vector< cell<double>* >`, a vector of pointers to C++ `cell` objects.

My Client code below shows an example of a call to this function (via the Python `CellComplex` method `elemen()`) and this appears to me to be working fine.  You will notice that my Python implementation of `elemen()` declares the return type  `lib.elemen.restype` to be an array of (Python) `Cell` objects.  That's what I get, `>>>print cmplx.elemen()` yields

`[<cellComplex_python.Cell_Array_8 object at 0x10d5f59e0>, 
 <cellComplex_python.Cell_Array_12 object at 0x10d5f5830>, 
 <cellComplex_python.Cell_Array_6 object at 0x10d5f58c0>, 
 <cellComplex_python.Cell_Array_1 object at 0x10d5f5950>]`

**But here's the problem:**

Now I want to call my C functions on one of the `Cell` objects in an array in this list.  For example, `cmplx.elemen()[0][0]` is a `<Cell object at 0x10d5f5b00>`, so in my mind I should be able to do this:

`cmplx.elemen()[0][0].dim()`, **but this segfaults**.

My suspicion is that I am not creating the custom Python classes `Cell` and `CellComplex` correctly.  In particular, in Python class `Cell`, method `dim(self):` I have the line `lib.dim.argtypes = [Cell]`, which must be absolutely bogus.  As well, I have this silly Python class `c_cellComplex` which does nothing except allow me to indicate to myself what a particular `ctypes.c_void_p` is supposed to point to.  In fact, I claim that my definitions of these Python classes are entirely bogus and I am being tricked into thinking I am on the right track by the miracle that this runs at all (up until I try to call a `Cell` method on a supposed `Cell` instance...

Client code:

```
p = [[0,1],[0,1]] 
cmplx = cellComplex(p)
e = cmplx.elemen()

e[0][0].dim() # segfault
```

**begin EDIT** [eryksun's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818377/390433) provides an example of how to subclass c_void_p, and addresses a few other conceptual issues - start there if you have the same questions I had.

The segfault issue comes from the fact that `get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim()` defined in `extern C { ...` returns a memory address to a `std::vector<cell<double>* >`, a datatype that cannot be parsed back in Python.  In this case I can just grab the pointers in the vector and return them, like so:

```
extern "C" {

  void * get_elementAtSpecifiedDimAndLoc(void *ptr, int dim, int nr) {
    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = static_cast<cellComplex<double>* >(ptr);
    cell<double>* c = cmplx->elemen()[dim][nr];
    return c;
  }
}
```

and can be called like so:

```
def elemen(self):    
     el = []
     for i in range(self.dim):
          size  = lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(self,i)               
          cells = []
          for j in range(size):
               cells.append(lib.get_elementAtSpecifiedDimAndLoc(self,i,j))            
          el.append(cells)
     return el
# put this somewhere
lib.get_elementAtSpecifiedDimAndLoc.restype  = Cell 
lib.get_elementAtSpecifiedDimAndLoc.argtypes = [CellComplex,c_int,c_int]
```

**The client code now works.**

**end EDIT**

Here is the magnificent folly:

```py
# cellComplex_python.py 
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./cellComplex_lib.so')

class c_cellComplex(ctypes.c_void_p):
     pass

class Cell(ctypes.c_void_p):

     def dim(self):
          lib.dim.restype  = ctypes.c_int
          lib.dim.argtypes = [Cell]
          self.dimension = lib.dim(self)
          return self.dimension

class CellComplex(ctypes.c_void_p):

     def __init__(self,p):   
          self.dimension = len(p)
          lib.new_cellComplex.restype  = c_cellComplex
          lib.new_cellComplex.argtypes = [(ctypes.c_double*2)*self.dimension, 
                                           ctypes.c_size_t]
          e = [(ctypes.c_double*2)(p[i][0],p[i][1]) for i in range(self.dimension)]
          point = ((ctypes.c_double*2)*self.dimension)(*e)
          self.cmplx = lib.new_cellComplex(point,self.dimension)


     def elemen(self):
          lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.restype  = ctypes.c_int
          lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.argtypes = [c_cellComplex,
                                                      ctypes.c_int]
          lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.argtypes  = [c_cellComplex,ctypes.c_int]

          self.sizeAtDim = []
          self.elements  = []
          for i in range(self.dimension+1):

               self.sizeAtDim.append(lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(self.cmplx,i))
               lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.restype = Cell*self.sizeAtDim[i]
               self.elements.append(lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(self.cmplx,i))

          return self.elements
```

`C` code:

```c
// cellComplex_extern.cpp
#include<"cell.hpp">
#include<"cellComplex.hpp"> 

extern "C" {

  void * new_cellComplex(double p[][2], size_t dim) {
    std::vector< std::pair<double,double> > point;
    for (size_t i=0; i<dim; ++i) {
      point.push_back( std::make_pair(p[i][0],p[i][1]));
    }   
    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = new cellComplex<double>(point);
    return cmplx;
  }

  void * get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(void *ptr, int dim) {
    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = static_cast<cellComplex<double>* >(ptr);
    std::vector<std::vector<cell<double>* > >* e = &cmplx->elemen();
    return &e[dim];
  }

  int size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(void *ptr, int dim) {
    cellComplex<double>* cmplx = static_cast<cellComplex<double>* >(ptr);
    return cmplx->elemen()[dim].size();
  }  

  int dim(void *ptr) {
    cell<double>* ref = static_cast<cell<double>* >(ptr);
    return ref->dim();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subclassing `c_void_p`, you can define the class method `from_param` and instance attribute `_as_parameter_`.  You may not need either option if you're just proxying a C++ object that's referenced in a private attribute such as `_obj`. That said, a subclass of `c_void_p` can be used directly with ctypes pointers, arrays, and structs, which may be convenient in your overall design.

The following example may help:

```
from ctypes import *

__all__ = ['CellComplex']

class Cell(c_void_p):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        raise TypeError("cannot create %r instances" % cls.__name__)

    @property
    def dimension(self):
        return lib.dim(self)

class CellComplex(c_void_p):

    def __init__(self, p):
        pair = c_double * 2
        point = (pair * len(p))(*(pair(*q[:2]) for q in p))
        self.value = lib.new_cellComplex(point, len(p)).value

    @property
    def dimension(self):
        """Wrap a function that returns size_t."""
        return lib.????????(self)

    def get_elements(self):
        el = []
        for i in range(self.dimension):
            size = lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(self, i)
            cells = lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim(self, i)
            el.append(cells[:size])
        return el
```

Function pointer definitions:

```
lib = CDLL('./cellComplex_lib.so')

lib.dim.restype = c_int
lib.dim.argtypes = [Cell]

lib.new_cellComplex.restype = CellComplex
lib.new_cellComplex.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double * 2), c_size_t]

lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.restype = c_int
lib.size_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.argtypes = [CellComplex, c_int]

lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.restype = POINTER(Cell)
lib.get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim.argtypes = [CellComplex, c_int]
```

I separated out the function pointer definitions from the class method definitions. There's no need to redefine a function pointer's `restype` and `argtypes` every time a method is called. If the function returns a variably sized array, you're better off setting it to a pointer type. You can slice the result to a list or `cast` to an array type.

`CellComplex` is initialized by a sequence `p` of floating point pairs such as `[[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6]]`.

I eliminated the `c_cellComplex` class. You can just set the instance's `value`.

`lib.new_cellComplex` returns an instance of `CellComplex`, but ctypes bypasses `__new__` and `__init__` when `CellComplex` is used as a `restype`, so that's not an issue. It would be less twisted to instead override `__new__`, but you'd still have to override `c_void_p.__init__`.

The `dimension` attribute needs to be a property that calls an exported function, instead of relying on static data in the Python object.

Comment: This is great!  I still suffer from the same behavior: `e = cmplx.elemen()` followed by `e[0][0].dim` still segfaults.  I think it's to do with the return of the `extern "C" ` function `get_elementsAtSpecifiedDim()`... I think I should be returning an array of pointers to (C++) cell objects rather than the memory address of a vector of pointers to (C++) cell objects.  Could you spare another moment to point(er) me in the right direction?

Comment: Nevermind eryksun - I've got it. Question edited to show my implementation of this feature.